# Lightbox integration problem

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter and I wanted to use "any" lightbox. I tried already slimbox2, facebox, prettyPhoto with the same result. I include css, js files in my head section ( with jquery of course). I added the images needed to appropriate folder.

in my gallery.php file I have

link to my image with the rel="prettyPhoto"

Just as it is shown in the prettyPhoto example.

Just before the ending body I added

script which executes the prettyPhoto. It executes those links with the rel = "prettyPhoto"

The problem is when I click on the link which should open the JS window with the image, it opens normal site with the image instead. I don't know it looks like it doesnt run the js... :/

```
htt p://screenshotuploader.com/s/YbwaOGMmMc
htt p://screenshotuploader.com/s/9BxmHdMwwt
htt p://screenshotuploader.com/s/uAftZndXhE0
```

some screenshots from firebug which i think doesnt recognize any problem :/ 
I would appreciate your help. Mabe you know some lightbox which is working for 100% with CI. I would be thankful if mabe someone could check whether the prettyPhoto is working with CI.

link for pretty photo

```
htt p://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#!prettyPhoto
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically all of them work if you set them up correctly. I just set up CI with slimbox in 60 secs. [Here](http://www.interaktivnost.net/lightbox.zip) is the zip, if you need to see it, but it's really really basic.

Answer (score 0):

codeIgniter won't interfere with jQuery or any lightbox plugin.  All of the php processing is done well before any js starts running.  So, any lightbox plugin will work "with" codeIgniter.

Make sure that there are no errors in your js code.  These will stop js processing, and may be keeping your lightbox code from executing. Also make sure that your selectors are correct.